# Logic behind this fuse status indicator

Tags: diodes, bjt, fuses

[image: Fuse With Status Indicator]

I was doing this circuit which I found on the Internet. My question is what is the logic behind the functioning of this circuit?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you see the text in the lower-left corner?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Simulating a circuit doesn't show _why_ a circuit behaves as it does. You can see currents and voltages changing, but it's not obvious why unless you know all the theory.

Answer (score 23):

Q1 and Q2 form a [astable multivibrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator) which will output a square wave (12V, 0 V, 12 V, 0 V, ...) voltage via D2. If D1 wasn't there then that square wave would turn on/off Q3 and with that also the LED. So the LED would **blink**.

However D1 is there and via R5 it keeps Q3 on even if the square wave voltage is 0 Volt. So the LED will not blink, it will be on continously.

But there is more. I didn't discuss fuse F1. If that fuse blows (due to overload or short circuit) then there will no longer be 12 V at R5 so R5 and D1 can no longer "overrule" the square wave voltage when it is 0 V. So that means that the LED will blink.

**So:**

Normal operation, fuse is intact: LED is continuously on

No power at output because the fuse has blown: the LED will blink

Oops, forgot the 3rd state:

When the LED is off, the battery is empty (assuming the circuit and LED are still working).

**Sidenote:** this circuit uses BC109 which is ancient. It will work just as well with more "modern" NPNs like BC549 or the not so modern but very cheap 2N2222.

Comment: BC109 is newer than 2N2222.

Comment: @pipe, I didn't know that. But BC109 is a "metal can" type making it look ancient, it is also expensive. 2N2222 looks more modern in a plastic TO92 housing and also much cheaper.

Comment: @ Bimpelrekkie The original 2N2222 was in metal-can. Plastic was not trusted to be hermetic.

Comment: They're all ancient anyway, I doubt it matters much. :)

Comment: I agree, any cheap NPN will do the job.

Comment: If I recall properly, the 2N2222 dates originally from around 1962.

Comment: Do you mean "astable multivibrator" where you have "multistable multivibrator"?

Comment: @zwol You're right, it should be astable, will edit